# Swipe delete button goes under custom UITableViewCell text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am having trouble with swipe delete button with custom `UITableViewCell`. When I swipe it, delete button goes under text in the cell. Below you can see the image and the code I am using.

Note: I draw tableviewcell in an xib.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //add code here for when you hit delete
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"HareketCell";

    HareketCell *cell = (HareketCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HareketCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    [cell.lblDakika setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[arrProgramim objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"dakika"], @" dk"]];

    [cell.imgThumbnail setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"most_harita_icon.png"]];

    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I use these two functions to swipe. The row includes custom tableviewcell. Can you please tell me what code do you want to see?

Comment: Are you adding the `UILabel` as a subview of the `contentView` of `UITableViewCell` or you are adding it as a subview of `UITableViewCell` itself?

Comment: Show us the code where you are adding subviews to the custom cell, please.

Comment: I have also added cellForRowAtIndexPath code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because you are not adding the `UILabel` as a subview of the `contentView` of `UITableViewCell`, you are adding it as a subview of `UITableViewCell` itself.

When you want to subclass a `UITableViewCell` and adding subviews to it, you should **always** add them inside the `contentView` of the cell.

This is from Apple's documentation of [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/contentView):

> If you want to go beyond the predefined styles, you can add subviews to the **contentView** property of the cell.

If you do it like that, iOS automatically adjusts everything inside contentView to show that delete button and nothing overlaps.

**Update:**

From the comments below, the cell is being created on a separate .xib, so the label is already a subview of cell's `contentView`

The problem is the loading of the NIB in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You have to register the NIB on table view beforehand, in `-viewDidLoad`, for example. Like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Assuming the xib is named HareketCell.xib
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"HareketCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"HareketCell"];
}
```

Now, change `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"HareketCell";

    HareketCell *cell = (HareketCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    [cell.lblDakika setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[arrProgramim objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"dakika"], @" dk"]];

    [cell.imgThumbnail setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"most_harita_icon.png"]];

    return cell;
}
```

You see, `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` already loads the NIB for you automatically, if you register it beforehand.

Comment: I have put UILabel in UIView and connected it to its property. now swipe delete button goes under UIView. Do you mean by contentView, UIView? I have added also code for cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I am setting label and image in XIB, in storyboard. I could not manage to add a subview to that cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath. could you please check my code that I have edited and added cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Oh, I see what the problem is. On `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you are creating a new cell based on the NIB, but you shouldn't do that at that point. I'll delete this answer and write a new one, but tell me where are you adding the subviews of the cell, on the .xib or inside a prototype table view in the storyboard? Maybe posting a screenshot of the cell in interface builder would help.

Comment: I directly add it in a view in xib. Like drag and drop and resize the xib as I want. Later I use the code above to display xib in tableview.

Comment: But did you do it inside the storyboard or on a new xib? Because I see you are loading a HareketCell.xib on `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: it is an external xib. not in storyboard. I was wrong in my previous answer in this conversation.

Comment: I am having SIGABRT error at dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier line after I placed the code in viewdidload. the error is: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString instantiateWithOwner:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16b004'. XIB Name is HareketCell.xib

Comment: I have changed the viewDidLoad code to this  [self.tableHareketler registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HareketCell"
                                               bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
         forCellReuseIdentifier:@"HareketCell"]; Now no error. But the button is still under label.

Comment: Shoot, I'm sorry, got confused with `-registerNib:...` method. But if the button is still under label, is very weird. There's something else not right, but right now I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. I have done exactly what you said but I is still under label.

Comment: I solved with content View. I was using it already but transferred to new app and it worked. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

i think this might be because u r label is too long... keep your label short and then try .. i think after making your label short you dont see the label overlappin on the delete button. If u cant find an answer to this you can always use a 3rd party library called SWTableViewCell which can be found here https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell